# I am new to programming and I can't tell if this error is occurring because of my syntax

Tags: java, syntax

```
package studentclient;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* Declare two object references of type Student s1 and s2 and instantiate two Student objects passing three arguments to the constructor for the class. Use different values for each class object */

    Student s1 = new Student("Dick Grayson", "666-66-6666", 3.80 );
    Student s2 = new Student("Jason Todd", "666-77-7777", 3.50 );

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    /* Output the name, social security number and GPA of the student from object reference s1 using the appropriate accessor methods(Get methods) to obtain the data */
    System.out.println("Student Information");

    System.out.println("Student Name: " + s1.getName());

    System.out.println("Student Social Security Number: " + s1.getSsn());

    System.out.println("Student GPA: " + s1.getGpa());

    /* Output the name, social security number and GPA of the student from object reference s2 using the toString method to return the data */
    System.out.println("Student Information");

    System.out.print(s2);

    /* Using the equals method and a selection control structure (if statement), compare objects s1 and s2 and output an appropriate message indicating if the objects are equal */

    if(s1.equals(s2)){

    System.out.println("Student's identities are equal!");

    }else {

    System.out.println("Student's identities are not equal!");

    }
    /* Using the appropriate mutator methods(Set Methods) on student object s2, change the name, social security number and GPA to the same values as in object s1. Use the set methods. */
       System.out.println("Enter new Student Information for Student 2: ");

       s2.setName("Dick Grayson");
       System.out.println("Student Name: " + s2.getName());

       s2.setSsn("666-66-6666");
       System.out.println("Student Social Security Number: " + s2.getSsn());

       s2.setGpa( 3.80 );
       System.out.println("Student GPA: " + s2.getGpa());

       /* Again, using the equals method and a selection control structure (if statement), compare objects s1 and s2 and output an appropriate message indicating if the objects are equal */
       if(s1.equals(s2)){
           System.out.println("Student's identities are equal!");
       }else{
           System.out.println("Student's identities are not equal!");
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is that for the second set of information s2 is clearly equal to s1, but my results keep saying that they are not equal. What should I do?
When I run it I get these results

Student Information
Student Name: Dick Grayson
Student Social Security Number: 666-66-6666
Student GPA: 3.8
Student Information
Name: Jason Todd
Social Security Number: 666-77-7777
GPA: 3.5
Student's identities are not equal!
Enter new Student Information for Student 2: 
Student Name: Dick Grayson
Student Social Security Number: 666-66-6666
Student GPA: 3.8
Student's identities are not equal!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Care to format your question properly. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the problem is is the equals method of student

Comment: Without the definition of `Student.equals` this is complicated to say what is wrong. Like said above, provide a [mcve], and I means, a really minimal example ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `equals` method with your custom object `Student`.

You need to override it in your `Student` class. In your case, if you want to match all fields of `s1` to `s2`, your implementation should go like this:

```
//Overriding equals
 public boolean equals(Object obj) 
  {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    Student that = (Student) obj;
    if (!this.name.equals(that.name)) return false;
    if (!this.ssn.equals(that.ssn)) return false;
    if (!this.gpa.equals(that.gpa)) return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Doing this will give you expected results when doing `s1.equals(s2)`.

But, say for example if you try to add these same objects `s1` and `s2` to a `Set`, it will consider them as different. The reason being, the hashcode for both will be different.

So, when you override `equals`, you should also override the `hashcode` method.

A sample implementation for it, considering you have some `Id` field in your `Student` class is:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int PRIME = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = PRIME * result + getId();
    return result;
}
```

You should use same fields to implement both `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

After doing this, your code should give you expected results.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Careful using `getClass` in an `equals` method. If you have some subclass that use the same comparision method (so don't redifined the method), this will fail as you could compare `Student` with one of his subclass, that will not work even if those should be equivalent. (Use `instanceof` if you really want)